# How to get a column from a latest doc in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The code to get couponId from document:

```
 function getLatestCouponId() {
 var cursor = db.collection('Coupon').find().limit(1).sort({ $natural : -1 });
 cursor.count(function(error, nbDocs) { 
    if (error) throw error;
    if(nbDocs == 0){
       couponId=1;
       insertData();
    }
    else if(nbDocs==1){
       cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) throw err;
                console.log('%j', docs);
                couponId = docs[0].couponId;
                
       });
                    
      insertData();
    }
  });
}
```

The above code tries to find the latest document in the collection coupon and find its coupon id column but unfortunately coupon id is returning null
console.log prints log as:

```
  [{"_id":"5a819ae4ee37582288837c9f","couponId":90,"district":"Thiruvananthapuram","taluk":"Thiruvananthapuram","landmark":"SCTIMST"}]
```

The code showing how I inserted docs into the collection is given below:

```
function insertData(){
    console.log("No of Coupons" + totalCoupon);
        //var newLandMark = { "hotelName": hotelName, "district": district, "taluk": taluk, "landmark":landmark,  "dateCreation": new Date(), 
    //};
    for(i=0;i<totalCoupon;i++){
    

        var doc ={"couponId":couponId, "district":district, "taluk":taluk, "landmark":landmark};
        docs.push(doc);
        couponId=couponId+1;;
    }
        db.collection('Coupon').insertMany(docs, {w: 1}, function(err, records){
            var itemsProcessed = 0;
            if (err) throw err;
            else{
                rdata["status"] = "ok";
                callback();

            } 
    
        });
        }
```

[doc which was logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZTtx.jpg)

[log from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUPbR.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @ponury-kostek please check that question is entirely different

Comment: Show us where and how you initialize and log `couponId`

Comment: Not sure what is your question, do you want to get the entire document?? or just one column?? Because it looks like you are geting the document properly.

Comment: Show us code not screen's of results :)

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla yeah i am getting the document but coupon Id Coluomn returns null.

Comment: So the problem should be in the document in your DB, check the document with the mongo shell or any other way you use.

Comment: Move `insertData();` into `cursor.toArray` callback

Comment: @ponury-kostek that solves the problem